# PHP - Product details POPUP

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting thoughts on how to best execute a javascript LightBox style popup for an 'add to cart' functional PHP script. The idea being products are listed in an grid with a 'details' link. Clicking the link launches a popup with a description and other php loaded variables which is then used to 'add to cart'.

I've seen some script that loads iframes. I was hoping there might be something cleaner. All options considered.

Cheers!

Comment: So.. how's this related to PHP or Java? Can you at least take 5 seconds to tag your question properly?

Comment: @N.B. - PHP script loading via Java, unrelated? How should I have tagged it?

Comment: Java != javascript, by a very large margin.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the jquery ui dialog, especially the modal form dialog.  You can put different option in there...

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

A good Idea would be to use Ajax. The Jquery Library offers some neat functions, but it also can be done in Javascript. Have a look at [jquery/ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
greets